# calculate the shortest time difference between event A & B, only when event B occurs after event A

Tags: sql, excel

For a particular user_id:
If Event A occurs, sometimes event B will occur, sometimes not.
But, if event B occurs, calculate the shortest time difference between event A & B.

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+    
| event_id  | user_id  |          timestamp          |     
+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+    
|        A  |       1  | January, 01 2021 10:40:00   |  
|        B  |       1  | January, 01 2021 14:40:00   |  
|        A  |       1  | January, 04 2021 13:30:00   |    
|        A  |       1  | January, 04 2021 19:30:00   |
|        A  |       1  | January, 05 2021 13:40:00   |
|        B  |       1  | January, 05 2021 16:40:00   |
+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

Here, for User =1: January, 01 2021: B-A = 4 hrs and for January, 05 2021: B-A = 3 hrs

How to implement this in MySQL or Excel ?

Comment: If **B** occurs after **A**, then you want the `Min(B's)-Max(A's)`

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: How do you compute six (6) hours difference from the information you present?  Seems to me it should be thirty (30) hours.

Comment: Corrected the dates

Comment: Not sure which db to use, I have excel files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a single event B occurs. You can do something like this, without going to the date calculation details as it depends on the database provider you are using:

```
SELECT MIN(B.timestamp - A.timestamp)
FROM T as A
INNER JOIN T as B 
ON (A.user_id  = B.user_id AND A.event_id != B.event_id AND B.timestamp > A.timestamp)
```

Comment: Used similar logic in Access to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions:

```
select user_id,
       min( next_b_timestamp - timestamp ) as shortest_ab_duration
from (select t.*,
             min(case when event_id = 'B' then timestamp end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as next_b_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where event_id = 'A'
group by user_id;
```

SQL Server probably wouldn't accept:

```
min( next_b_timestamp - timestamp ) as shortest_ab_duration
```

Instead, you can use:

```
min( datediff(minute, timestamp, next_b_timestamp) ) as shortest_ab_duration_minutes
```

Comment: Thanks, I used Access, not sure if it would support this.

Comment: @TEKSOL . . . You question **explicitly** says MySQL.  Why are you providing misinformation in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I had to change the database due to the people who will be using it.